# Kernel debugging - gdb step jumps out of function

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel, qemu

I'm trying to do understand the kernel network stack for a security research for my university. That's why I try to debug the linux kernel.

So far I'm doing quite well but I ran in a problem when trying to use qemu and gdb for debugging.

The problem is as follows:

I boot my linux system: make boot

```
   boot:
        @qemu-system-x86_64 \
            -kernel ${KERNEL_IMAGE} \
            -drive file=${DRIVE_IMAGE},index=0,media=disk,format=raw \
            -append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0 nokaslr gdbwait" \
            -m ${RAM} \
            --nographic \
            --enable-kvm  \
            -s
```

And connect with gdb: make debug

```
debug:
    @gdb -iex "target remote localhost:1234" ${KERNEL_DIRECTORY}/vmlinux
```

I set a breakpoint e.g. at icmp_rcv and continue

```
b icmp_rcv
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff81808910: file net/ipv4/icmp.c, line 989.
c
```

Know I ping myself -> breakpoint hit:

```
Breakpoint 1, icmp_rcv (skb=0xffff88007c24ee00) at net/ipv4/icmp.c:989
```

Great so far everything worked as expected.
Know I press n/s (next or step) and instead of net/ipv4/icmp.c:990
It says:

```
native_apic_mem_write (reg=896, v=52414) at ./arch/x86/include/asm/apic.h:99
```

Know I press n until I come back to icmp_rcv:989.
I tried to set a breakpoint to icmp_rcv_990 but gdb never stops there.
Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I have no glue why but removing `--enable-kvm` from my Makefile helped to get it working. I hope this helps other people.

Comment: I still have the problem, on a similar file, IGMP.c; Did you found something other helpful?